# nlinfit command in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, 3d, curve-fitting

I'm given data for x,y, and z. I am trying to fit a set of data into a model of functional form as described below:

```
z(x, y) = c0*x^o*y2 + c1*x^1*y^1 + c2 *x^2*y^1
```

where c0, c1, c2 are the coefficients to be found.
My attempt is to use the nlinfit function to solve it.

So far I have tried

```
x= [ 0.001, .. 0.011];

y = [1, .. 10];

z = [ -.304860225 .. .379710865]; 

my_model= c0 * x^0 * y^2 + c1 * x^1 * y^1 + c2 * x^2 * y^0

[c0 c1 c2] = [1 2 3];

C= nlinfit( [x,y], z, @ my_model, [1 2 3])
```

Here `x`,`y` are independent variables and `z` is dependent variable. 
How can one set these initial values for the coefficients? 
I'm not sure how to pass the arguments in `nlinfit` function. HELP!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model is LINEAR w.r.t `c0`, `c1` and `c2`. There's no reason to use `nlfit` here.

You need to construct a [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) for your `x` `y` data and use backslash to recover the coefficients.

It is not 100% clear from your question what the model is, so I'll assume:

```
z(x,y) = c0 * x^nx0 * y^ny0 + c1 * x^nx1 * y^ny1 + c2 * x^nx2 * y^ny2
```

with `nx0`, `nx1`, `nx2`, `ny0`, `ny1` and `ny2` given and known a-priori.

You are given `m` points, that is an `m`-vectors `x`, `y` and `z` and you wish to extimate `c0` `c1` and `c2` given these three `m`-vectors.

The Vandermonde matrix for this model is

```
V = [ ( x(:).^nx0 ).*( y(:).^ny0 ),  ( x(:).^nx1 ).*( y(:).^ny1 ),  ( x(:).^nx2 ).*( y(:).^ny2 ) ];
```

Now note that your model is LINEAR: `V*c = z` for the right `c = [c0; c1; c2]`.

To recover `c` (in the least-square sense)

```
c = V \ z
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just ramdomly added values for c0, c1, c2. How can one set these initial values for the coefficients? I have to perform non-linear curve fitting

Comment: @Syeda your curve may be non-linear, but the fitting is linear!

Comment: @ Shai.. So, there is no need to use nlfit function in my case? I run this code in MATLAB. Could you please help me understand why i am getting this error? "??? Undefined function or variable 'c0' "

Comment: @Syeda you do NOT need to use `nlfit`. `V` is non linear w.r.t `x` and `y`, but `z` is linear w.r.t known `V` and unknown `c`.

Comment: @Syeda what code have you tired to run? I have no `c0` in my code?

Comment: @Shai.. I have tried my code. I am not getting how to set the coefficients in the code. Anyways, thankyou for introducing me to Vandermonde matrix.

Comment: @Syeda can you be more specific? I might be able to help. Are you able to construct `V`? Are you able to perform `V\z(:)`? what is the size of `c=V\z(:)`? this should be a three vector with the coeff you are looking for.

Comment: @ Shai.. yes! I got it. Thankyou! :) V is constructed and my output is :-
c=
0.0050
-0.4113
934.2137

Comment: @ Shai.. So, now i put these coefficients in my proposed model? Right. I actually want to see it through some 3D plot or anything like that to assure that data has been fit in my equation!